# XML to php issues with undefined variables

Tags: php, xml

So I have this returning from an api xml call:

In the browser:

```
string(1005) " 0 0 56000 steadfast shared semidedicated dedicated vps vps_solusvm london shared vps vps_solusvm australia sis_group shared vps_solusvm 0.017 s 0.010 s 8676395012 "
```

In the Google Chrome Elements:

```
<ampa>
<command></command>0
<error_code>0</error_code>
<ttl>56000</ttl>
<datacenters>
    <n0>
        <name>steadfast</name>
        <description><!--[CDATA[SteadFast/Chicago, United States]]--></description>
        <services>
            <n0>shared</n0>
            <n1>semidedicated</n1>
            <n2>dedicated</n2>
            <n3>vps</n3>
            <n4>vps_solusvm</n4>
        </services>
    </n0>
    <n1>
        <name>london</name>
        <description><!--[CDATA[BlueSquare/London, United Kingdom]]--></description>
        <services>
            <n0>shared</n0>
            <n1>vps</n1>
            <n2>vps_solusvm</n2>
        </services>
    </n1>
    <n2>
        <name>australia</name>
        <description><!--[CDATA[Global Switch/Sydney, Australia]]--></description>
        <services>
        </services>
    </n2>
    <n3>
        <name>sis_group</name>
        <description><!--[CDATA[SiSGroup/Sydney, Australia]]--></description>
        <services>
            <n0>shared</n0>
            <n1>vps_solusvm</n1>
        </services>
    </n3>
</datacenters>
<execution_time>0.017 s</execution_time>
<db_time>0.010 s</db_time>
<uniq_id>8676395012</uniq_id>
```

Now I try to achieve a very simple call like so:

```
echo $result->ampa->datacenters->n0->name;
```

and get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What am I doing wrong with processing this xml?

BTW my backend code looks like this:

```
function index() {
    $result = $this->rest->get('/?auth_username=the-green-panda&auth_password=MacBook1&section=datacenters&command=get_datacenters');

    var_dump($result);

    echo '<hr/>';

    echo $result->ampa->datacenters->n0->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the XML is missing the closing `</ampa>` tag.

Don't include the `ampa`. Just go with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->datacenters->n0->name;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/128482)

Comment: I recieve three `Trying to get property of non-object` errors. I'm assuming one for datacenters, n0, and name

Comment: Please check the demo in the answer. Your **XML** is not valid. You need to add the `</ampa>` at the end of your XML.

Comment: I was missing `simplexml_load_string();` very new to xml.